# Parse.com : current user not available in other page after login

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, forms-authentication

I have a page witch check currentUser (index.html). 
If the current user not available, I open a login page (login.html).

```
Parse.initialize (API,JSKEY);
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
if (!currentUser) {
    location.href="login.html";
}
```

In the new page, I call the login function.

```
Parse.initialize (API,JSKEY);
var username = document.formLogin.email.value;
var password = document.formLogin.pwd.value;

// Call Parse Login function with those variables
Parse.User.logIn(username,password , {
    success: function(user) {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
        console.log("Connexion OK");
        location.href("index.html");
    },
        error: function(user, error) {
        // The login failed. Check error to see why.
        alert("error login");
    }
    });
```

The login function return success. I look at the local storage and the cookie of currentUser is present. So I reload the first page, witch check currentUser.
And surprise, the currentUser is not present (there is no cookies), so the login page is recalled.

If I close all the pages of my browser, and I reopen the first page(index.html), the currentUser is present and the login page is not open.

Why the currentUser is available only if I reopen the page, please? If you have an idea, let me know ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Have you initialized parse:-


     Parse.initialize(API,JSKEY);
```

or check [Parse Initialize](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.html). If already initialized then check the result of currenUser:-

```
     console.log(currenUser);
```

Comment: Yep, in the 2 .js file, I initialize with the same parse.initialize and console.log(currentUser) is null.

Comment: it seems it's a problem with safari. The cookies currentUser is not visible between the 2 pages. If I close all the page and reload, the cookies is detected and the login is not displayed. 
It works well in chrome.